# In C++, how do you create a map of int and iterator of current map?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to create something like this:

```
map<int, iterator> first, second;
```

Here value of iterator in the first map will point to and entry in second map and the iterator field in the second map will point to the first map.

This is to sort a key and a value corresponding to the key.

Comment: @RSahu It requires infinite recursion in the type specifier, which I guess is why OP is asking the question. OP: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is?

Comment: @uneven_mark, I did not notice declaration of `second`. You're right.